# Cant use range in golang

Tags: go

For some reason I cant iterate with range

```golang
var sessionStore = make(FileSystemStore)
func LsSessionsCommand(_ []string, _ *string, _ *memory.FileSystem){
    w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 1, 1, 1, ' ', 0)
    fmt.Fprint(w, "id\tstored time\n")
    
    for key, val := range sessionStore {
        // never reaches here
        t := time.Unix(val.Stored, 0)
        createdTime := fmt.Sprintf("%d:%d %d/%d/%d", t.Hour(), t.Minute(), t.Day(), t.Month(), t.Year())
        _, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\t%s\n", key, createdTime)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("unable to list sessions: %v", err)
        }
    }
    err := w.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to list sessions: %v", err)
    }
}
```

`sessionStore`'s `type` is `FileSystemStore`

```golang
type FileSystemStore map[string]FileSystemStoreEntry

type FileSystemStoreEntry struct {
    FS FileSystem
    Stored int64
}
```

Adding `data` to `sessionStore`

```golang
func StashSession(memfs memory.FileSystem, id string) {
    s := sessionStore[id]
    s.FS = memfs
    s.Stored = time.Now().Unix()

    memfs.ReplaceFS(memory.CreateMemoryFileSystem().MFileSystem)
}
```

Reading `data`

```golang
func CollectSession(memfs memory.FileSystem, id string, stashCurrent bool, newid string) {
    s := sessionStore[id]
    fs := s.FS.MFileSystem
    if stashCurrent {
        s.FS = memfs
    }
    memfs.ReplaceFS(fs)
}
```

I can `read` and `write` data to `sessionStore` but can't iterate over it.
When i call the `LsSessionsCommand()` The output I get `id    stored time`
it just never reaches the body of the range function.

I first called `StashSession` function, then `LsSessionsCommand` function

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Did you read example code using iteration? As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: When you say you "can't iterate with range", what does that mean? What happens? Also, can you show the declaration of `sessionStore`, and check that it isn't empty when you're ranging over it?

Comment: Based on what's shown and what you're describing, it would appear that when that `for` is executed, `sessionStore` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see is that your saving logic is faulty, and I suspect you aren’t able to iterate the map because it is in fact empty.

Here

```
func StashSession(memfs memory.FileSystem, id string) {
    s := sessionStore[id]
    s.FS = memfs
    s.Stored = time.Now().Unix()
    //...
}
```

You aren’t adding a new element in the map. For that you’d need to:

```
sessionStore[id] = FileSystemStoreEntry{
    FS: memfs,
    Stored: time.Now().Unix(),
    //....
}
```